# OData: get entity by key but without entity set name

Tags: odata

In my system, all entities have unique identifiers of type GUID. So, from the end-user perspective, it makes sense to ask for entity just by its key without specifying the type: `/odata/objects(0000000-000000000-000000000-0000000)`

Is it allowed in OData?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-cs01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_ResourcePath

As you can read here in the official OData docs, this is the recommended format but you are not required to follow it. 
But if you are using some library like Olingo, then I think they make it compulsory to follow these rules.